# 在 in front of the nouns like tomorrow or exact dates and time

Tags: grammar, meaning, word

Do we need to put 在 before 明天 三点钟 星期五 in such sentences like 早在八月我们就开发了一个愿型，or 我是在1997年喜欢上汉语 or 我在八月到的上海?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you use the time term as independent qualifier (can't add 在) or as part of a phrase, especially the prepositional phrase (在 usually must be added), and my suggestion is to avoid this type.

我是在1997年喜欢上汉语 vs 我(是)1997年喜欢上汉语(的), 是 and 的 purely for emphasizing;

我在八月到的上海 vs 我八月到(的)上海, again, 的 for emphasizing.

Also, I recommended try to avoid using 在 at the beginning of a sentence whether to introduce time or place, unless you really want to emphasize "among/during":

在北京，八月最热。   在八月，北京最热。  both sound weird, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put `在` in your examples. And...

1. Pay attention to words like today/tomorrow, you can only add `在` when the time goes as a noun rather an adverb.
   `希望就在明天`
   `明天会更美好`: do not put `在` before.
2. In particular, for the first example, `在` must be added, check the differences below.
   `早在八月...`: since August.
   `早八月...`: error.
   `（在）八月初...`:  in early August.

Answer (score 0):

```
在北京，八月最热。 在八月，北京最热。 both sound weird, right?
```

It's no problem for native user.

e.g.

```
Q1: 北京一年裡最熱甚麼時候？ 
A1: 在北京，八月最熱。

Q2: 八月中國哪邊最熱？
A2: 在八月，北京最熱。

Q3: 我今天傍晚可以跟你見個面嗎？
A3: 在七點的時候我跟朋友會在台北101吃飯，你早點來，我們可以聊一下。
```